# Can one derive charged black hole solution of GR using Kaluza-Klein?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

Kaluza-Klein showed that a 5 dimensional gravitional theory with one dimension on a circle, is equivalent in the limit to a 4 dimensional gravitational theory with electromagnetism.

So for the Reissner–Nordström metric for a charged black hole, could we derive this from the 5 dimensional Schwarzschield solution and then compactify one dimension?

I'm not sure where the charge $Q$ would come from though as the 5 dimensional solution would only have one free paramter $M$. Perhaps it would come from the radius of the compact dimension.

The reason I was thinking about this is it seems like why consider electromagnetism and gravity separately when there is the Kaluza-Klein mechanism.

Comment: There are many different models including https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505038